# Convert String returned by Promise to Array

Tags: arrays, json, react-native, promise

I'm having trouble converting the string returned by a promise to an array.  The promise is returned by AsyncStorage in React Native.  I've tried JSON.parse and  .split() but I don't think I'm using them correctly.  I need to be able to call specific key value pairs form the array afterwards.  Please let me know if you have any suggestions. I've included my code, a screenshot of the error and the returned values in the console log

```
onLocationsSelectionChange = (locationsSelected) => {
console.log("does this work", locationsSelected, this.state.locationsSelected.length)
AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:locationsSelected', JSON.stringify(this.state.locationsSelected));

const myArray = AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:locationsSelected')
console.log('test Array', (myArray));
console.log('myArray', JSON.parse(myArray))
this.setState({locationsSelected});
```

};

Image: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEdlg.png]

Comment: `myArray` isn't an array, it's a `Promise`.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickRoberts!  I know its a Promise being returned by AsyncStorage.  It starts as an array in my code, then I convert to string to save to AsyncStorage on line 3.  When I use AsyncStorage.getItem to retrieve the data, it returns as a string since this is how--to my knowledge--AsyncStorage saves its data.  My issue is converting the data back from a promise to an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `AsyncStorage` documentation, you should get your item like this:

```
_retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('TASKS');
    if (value !== null) {
      // Here use JSON.parse(value)
    }
   } catch (error) {
     // Error retrieving data
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense Oma!